# Istio configuration on GKE

Tags: istio, gke-networking

I have some basic questions about Istio. I installed Istio for my Tyk API gateway. Then I found that simply installing Istio will cause all traffic between the Tyk pods to be blocked. Is this the default behaviour for Istio? The Tyk gateway cannot communicate with the Tyk dashboard.

When I rebuild my deployment without Istio, everything works fine.

I have also read that Istio can be configured with virtual services to perform traffic routing. Is this what I need to do for every default installing of Istio? Meaning, if I don't create any virtual services, then Istio will block all traffic by default?

Secondly, I understand a virtual service is created as a YAML file applied as a CRD. The host name defined in the virtual service rules - in a default Kubernetes cluster implementation on Google Cloud, how do I find out the host name of my application?

Lastly, if I install Tyk first, then later install Istio, and I have created the necessary label in Tyk's nanmespace for the proxy to be injected, can I just perform a rolling upgrade of my Tyk pods to have Istio start the injection?

For example, I have these labels in my Tyk dashboard service. Do I use the value called "app" in my virtual service YAML?

```
labels:
    app: dashboard-svc-tyk-pro
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    chart: tyk-pro-0.8.1
    heritage: Helm
    release: tyk-pro
```

Sorry for all the basic questions!

Answer (score 1):

For question on Tyk gateway cannot communicate with the Tyk dashboard.
(I think the problem is that your pod tries to connect to the database before the Istio sidecar is ready. And thus the connection can't be established.
Istio runs an init container that configures the pods route table so all traffic is routed through the sidecar. So if the sidecar isn't running and the other pod tries to connect to the db, no connection can be established. Ex case: [Application running in Kubernetes cron job does not connect to database in same Kubernetes cluster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65707362/application-running-in-kubernetes-cron-job-does-not-connect-to-database-in-same/65708039#65708039))

For question on Virtual Services
2.Each virtual service consists of a set of routing rules that are evaluated in order, letting Istio match each given request to the virtual service to a specific real destination within the mesh.
By default, Istio configures the Envoy proxies to passthrough requests to unknown services. However, you can’t use Istio features to control the traffic to destinations that aren’t registered in the mesh.

For question on hostname refer to [this documentation](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/service-entry/#ServiceEntry).

The hosts field lists the virtual service’s hosts - in other words, the user-addressable destination or destinations that these routing rules apply to. This is the address or addresses the client uses when sending requests to the service.

Adding Istio on GKE to an existing cluster please refer to [this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/istio/docs/istio-on-gke/installing#adding_istio_on_gke_to_an_existing_cluster).

If you want to update a cluster with the add-on, you may need to first resize your cluster to ensure that you have enough resources for Istio. As when creating a new cluster, we suggest at least a 4 node cluster with the 2 vCPU machine type.If you have an existing application on the cluster, you can find out how to migrate it so it's managed by Istio as mentioned in the Istio documentation.
You can uninstall [the add-on following document](https://cloud.google.com/istio/docs/istio-on-gke/uninstalling) which includes to shift traffic away from the Istio ingress gateway.Please take a look at [this doc](https://cloud.google.com/istio/docs/istio-on-gke/overview#whats_installed) for more details on installing and uninstalling Istio on GKE.

Also adding [this document](https://cloud.google.com/istio/docs/istio-on-gke/installing) for installing Istio on GKE which also includes installing it to an existing cluster to [quickly evaluate Istio](https://istio.io/latest/docs/setup/getting-started/#step_3_deploy_the_bookinfo_sample_application).

Comment: According to the documentation Istio isn't supported on GKE anymore (quite confusing as to why).