# istio default installation - traffic blocked?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, redis, google-kubernetes-engine, istio

I'm quite new to Istio.

I just installed Istio on a k8 cluster in GCP. I have 2 services in my private cluster. one of them needs to talk to a Redis memorystore (over internal private IP - 10.x.x.x).

I'm seeing errors trying to connect to redis. What am I missing in my Istio configuration?

Update: I have found that the redis error is misleading. The real issue it seems is something else - see one my comments below. I don't understand what that error means.

Some additional background: this is for a Tyk installation. The issue it seems is communication between the Tyk Dashboard and Tyk Gateway pods. I'm seeing the SSL error (see comments below) when trying to connect from Gateway to Dashboard (Dashboard to Gateway is fine). The error goes away if I rebuild everything without Istio. I must be doing something really silly. :( Both pods are in the same cluster, same namespace.

Comment: what doesn't make sense to me is that istio is supposed to allow egress traffic to external services by default. why is the redis connection failing.

Comment: Does it only fail on pod startup? Traffic from an app needs the istio-sidecar proxy to work, if the request is before successful sidecar startup it will fail. See this anser: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65708039/10020419

Comment: @jsy, could you edit the question by adding your redis error? Please attach also your Istio configuration.

Comment: No, it's not. I'm quite sure of that. The pods have an uptime of 9 hours. I can't imagine sidecar injection taking 9 hours. Furthermore, the connection failure to redis is being retried every 10 seconds. I'm actually deploying Tyk with Istio. Hmmm.....

Comment: wait. i'm now seeing this: "curl <redacted>/hello
upstream connect error or disconnect/reset before headers. reset reason: connection failure, transport failure reason: TLS error: 268435703:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:WRONG_VERSION_NUMBERI have no name!@gateway-tyk-pro-t4bc2:/opt/tyk-gateway$." I'll go investigate..

Comment: @MikołajGłodziak 
Can you elaborate on what you mean by Istio configuration? (Sorry I am quite new to Istio) I have not defined any virtual services, destination rules, etc. It is a pure vanilla installation of Istio using the default profile.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix the issue. Redis wasn't the issue. Issue was communication from Tyk Gateway -> Tyk Dashboard was failing. The gateway talks to the dashboard to register its presence. The connection logs showed what looked like a tls origination issue with Istio envoy proxy when it is routing the traffic. I configured a DestinationRule that explicitly turned off mtls for the dashboard and the problem went away.

Comment: had you tried creating a `SeviceEntry` object for that endpoint?

Comment: I have fixed it. Destination rule.

Comment: you didn't fix it, you worked around it, by disabling mtls. but whatever. important that you feel good with what you have done.

Comment: What should be the correct approach then? Re-enable mtls and have the dashboard and gateway turn off tls communications?